# My GUI still freezes after implementing QThread

Tags: multithreading, pyqt6

So I have been writing a GUI to compress TIF files. libraries used are osgeo gdal and rasterio, aside from PyQt. I followed a tutorial on PyQt Threading [here](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/) and it initially worked for me, at least I think so.

Later on, I'm at lost at what change I had done that make it doesn't work anymore but my GUI now freezes while performing the compress function which I put inside a worker class.

Here is the code for the container of the worker class inside my MainWindow class:

```
def compress_worker(self):

        #check if input is valid
        if self.error_check():
            return None
        
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("color: black")

        self.label_5.setText("Compressing...")

        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        # Step 6: Start the thread
        
        self.thread.start()

        self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_4.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(True)
        )
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.pushButton_4.setEnabled(True)
        )
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.label_5.setText("Finished!")
        )
```

and here is the compress function inside the worker class:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        

        compression=["JPEG","LZW","DEFLATE"]
        output_filename = destfolder + r"\tile_"

        #open file using rasterio to get dimensions
        raster = rast.open(inputfile)
        
        #determine the number of files generated (divide by 4 means 4 rows, 4 columns, 16 files total)
        tile_size_x = int((raster.width/tiles)+(raster.width%tiles != 0))
        tile_size_y = int((raster.height/tiles)+(raster.height%tiles != 0))
        
        ds = gdal.Open(inputfile)
        band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
        xsize = band.XSize
        ysize = band.YSize

        iteration = 0
        
        for i in range(0, xsize, tile_size_x):
            for j in range(0, ysize, tile_size_y):

                #try delete file if it already exists
                try:
                    os.remove(str(output_filename) + str(i) + "_" + str(j) + ".tif")
                except OSError:
                    pass

                dest = str(output_filename) + str(i) + "_" + str(j) + ".tif"
                options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format="GTIFF",widthPct=compression_level,heightPct=compression_level,creationOptions=["COMPRESS="+compression[compression_index]],srcWin=[i,j,tile_size_x,tile_size_y])
                gdal.Translate(dest,inputfile,options=options)
                iteration = iteration + 1
                self.progress.emit(iteration)
        
        self.finished.emit()
```

I've tried removing some lines of codes and see if it still freezes and it did. I also made sure not to manipulate any PyQt widgets in my worker thread, but it still freezes the same.

I know questions like this had been asked before but none of the solutions helped me. Would greatly appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySide6 QThread still freezing main GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72737506/pyside6-qthread-still-freezing-main-gui)

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre].